# Removing Unused ASPX pages from ASP.NET Forms Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions

Clean Up question: I am working on a large ASP.NET FORM 4.0+ project where there are many legacy pages.

Before I start a timely process of elimination. I wanted to reach out to determine any extensions in Visual Studio that can analyze unused or not referenced, or not linked to any web page report anymore.

Another thought is I do have about 6 months of IIS logs I could run web traffic reports remove any page not showing up in the reports.

Share your wisdom please, the project is over 5000 asp.net pages

Primary reasons for cleanup:
- Project will build much faster..
- Allow adding other developers to the project will be sanitized..

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to reach out to determine any extensions in Visual Studio
>   that can analyze unused or not referenced, or not linked to any web
>   page report anymore.

**After a long research**, there is no such vs extension for VS2019 to remove any used aspx pages so far.

But there is an extension called [FindUnusedFiles](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RobertHoffmann.FindUnusedFiles) which applies to VS2015 or earlier version. It has not been updated to use in VS2017+. So as a suggestion, you can write a review under `Rating & Review` in this link. Try to contact with the author to apply it in VS2019.

**Besides**,I recommend you could post a feature request in [our User Voice forum(DC)](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html)----suggest a feature to share your idea with the staff to add the function into VS2019.

After you post it, you could share the link in this thread and anyone who is interested in this including us will vote it to get the attention of Microsoft as soon as possible.

Hope it could help you.